# How to highlight the warning in Pycharm automatically?

Tags: python, python-2.7

[image]

I'm using `Pycharm` and have two scripts in same directory , one is called `database_helper.py` and another is `test.py`

I defined some constants in `database_helper`, for example database `DATABASE_NAME` and `COLUMN_FAMILY`,  and then in script `test.py` uses `import database_helper`  and get use column family as `database_helper.COLUMN_FAMILY` everything works fine.

The problem is that I modified `COLUMN_FAMILY` to `TABLE` in script `databse_helper.py` and removed `*.pyc` files,  but there's no highlight warnings say `COLUMN_FAMILY` is unavailable except I put cursor on it.

The reason why I am asking is I thought my script was properly but failed when running on a remote server, I figured out this issue after debugging.

Why no complaining about this `AttributeError` by `Pycharm`? Is there anyone know how to make the warning highlighted?

Comment: PYCHARM already provides the warnings and notifications automatically with different color codes. You can also see the RED colored marks in the vertical scroll bar in the right hand side.

Comment: @PralhadNarsinhSonar  there's no red highlighted mark on the right side bar, it is really odd.

Comment: Option #1 - Please see if Python path is getting resolved in your PyCharm IDE. Please visit https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Syntax+highlighting+and+error+indication - this should surely help you out.

Comment: can you check your settings / editor / inspections / python / "Unresolved references"?

Comment: @JörnHees Thanks! you saved my life.  It was marked as warning level with yellow color, now I modified it to Error level and red, now it is working! Please move your comment to answer area, I'll accept it.

Comment: you're welcome, it's quite easy to disable them once by accident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the warning level of this kind of inspection under

```
Settings / Editor / Inspections / Python / "Unresolved references"
```

Yours was probably switched off / set to be a weak warning.